# Present action in past tense

Tags: grammar

Sir,  I am really  confused about this sentence:

- *Thank you for watching my Youtube channel*.

Does the observation verb 'watching'  act here as a  gerund  (it is happening now) or act as a past action?

Comment: It's a verbal -ing form usage (the term 'gerund' is variously defined and best forgotten), and gives no clue about whether the viewing is in the past, present, future even [this a hopeful or cheeky usage], or any mixture.

Comment: It's a gerund.  Gerunds have no tense, leaving us free to assume anything that makes sense about the time of the watching.

Comment: @Greg Lee Ah; definition number 16 (or is it 13?) As per McCawley?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, No, just a simple observation.  Look -- there is no present or past there in the form.  (I wasn't disagreeing with you.)

Comment: @Greg Lee 'It's a gerund' is what I find unacceptable. I've come across various conflicting definitions. One includes all V ..... N ing-forms.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I never used the term "gerund" until I started reading questions and answers in this very forum.  I think I've learned how to use it now, by observation.  It means -ing form of a verb used in nominalized sentences.

Comment: 'A nominalized form' begs the question. The by now infamous 'Brown's deftly painting his daughter was a delight to watch' has a 'nominalised' ing form only if you select your tests for nominalisation at the expense of tests for verbstayingputalisation in certain ways. CGEL adopts the 'gerund-participial' label / lumping approach, eschewing the term 'gerund'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I think you're right. Consider _Thank you for attentively watching my YouTube channel._ Now nouns (the gerund **watching** ) ain't modified by adverbs, are they?

Comment: @405... ACGEL (Quirk et al) classify your example differently from 'Brown's deftly painting his daughter was a delight to watch'; the latter has the ing-form not only modified by an adverb but also part of a possessive construction. The only way to ascribe a single POS here is to select which test/s should be given highest status. There are even tests to decide this! Quirk on the other hand prefers a gradience model, saying something like 'this [here, a hypothetical] example lies somewhere along the noun ... verb continuum, say 70% verb'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Ah, how could I miss that? Indeed, "ing-forms" can be modified by adverbs as your example shows. Care to expatiate on _There are even tests to decide this!_ a bit more, please? Or suggest a link/s, perhaps? :)

Comment: CGEL (Huddleston et al) lump at least a lot of these ing-form variants into what they term 'gerung-participles' (if I remember correctly) while ACGEL (Quirk et al) believe that that's too broad-brush and prefer a gradience approach. Look up 'gerund', 'ing-form' and 'gradience' (and _Aarts_ for an overview), here on ELU and elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Edwin Ashworth!! :)

Answer (score 1):

The  context tells the  time.

we  usually  say  thank you  or  sorry  just  after  completion  of  an  action.

> **Thank  you  for watching  my  you tube channel**

since  somebody has already  watched  the  channel,you  can  say  the  above  sentence.

> **I am  sorry  for  taking  your  pen**

You  say  sorry after  taking  the  pen.  so  the  time  of  the  action is completed  in the  present( present perfect)

Both  the  sentences may  be used  in  oral communication  since  the  time  of  the  action is  implied  and  completed  in  the  present moment.

I think    watching  and  taking  are  present  participles  or   simply  ingforms.

Without the  context  we  can  not  tell  the time  forwhich  the  sentences  are  used.

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of my native language, "watching" in this sentence plays a role of a noun. To be more specific, it's a name of the activity. In that sense it's not a verb at all, thus it isn't placed in time on it's own.

Comment: What is your native language and how does that relate to the English language?

Comment: Those grammarians who must classify every usage would almost all say that this instance of 'watching' has an object and thus falls in the 'verb' camp. I'm with the gradience school here, and would say it exhibits both nominal and verbal properties, being slightly nearer the verb terminus.

Comment: @KillingTime my native language is Polish and in the case of this sentence we would decline Polish equivalent of "watching" the same way we decline nouns. The sentence is simple enough to allow for a word-for-word translation.